# redhat上で起動した「talend open studio」で日本語入力ができない

Tags: linux

Windows 環境上では問題なく日本語入力を行うことができたのですが、 Redhat6.2 上で起動した Talend Open Studio で日本語入力を行うことができませんでした。

実行手順としては下記を行っています。

1. X Windowを起動。
2. リモート接続のため Xming を起動。
3. Talend Open Studio を起動。
   （GNOME上では日本語入力が可能なことを確認しています。）

日本語 IME として ibus を使用しています

この場合、 Linux 版の Talend Open Studio は日本語入力に対応していないのでしょうか？
それとも、環境の言語設定の問題なのでしょうか？

また、環境の言語設定の問題である場合は 「Japanese Support」 のインストール以外に何の設定が必要なのでしょうか？

ご存知の方がいれば教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

申し訳ありません。

「Xming」の言語設定の問題で、下記コマンドを実行することで解決いたしました。
ibus-daemon -d -x

Comment: 解決したことを示すため、自身で回答を承認して頂ければと思います。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers